# How to deal with different folders in webpack to change src of image in dist?

Tags: javascript, html, webpack

Here is my dir:
-src
--assets
----images
--html
--js
--styles
My html img tag looks like:

```
<img src='../assets/images/image.png'>
```

When build is made dist folder is:
-dist
--assets
----images
--index.html
--index.js
--index.css
But the path in image tag remains the same, so the problem is that it's trying to reach ../assets instead of ./assets
I want the directory structure remain the same but to change these paths dynamically, also I don't want to import my images through js or css
Here is the part of my webpack config:

```
entry : {
        main: '~src/js/index.js'
    },
    output : {
        filename : '[name].[hash].js',
        path : path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist')
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([
            {
                from: './src/assets',
                to: 'assets'
            }
        ])
    ].concat(htmlPlugins),
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
                use: [ImageminPlugin.loader, 
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            name: '[name].[ext]',
                            outputPath: 'assets/images'
                        }
                    }
                ],
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: Why you're not using the same `webpack` build for the dev environment also?

Comment: I am, in dev in works but in production doesnt

Comment: After the build the directory structure should be same like the production then how it doesn't work?

Comment: it is the same and the paths remain the same (wrong) but it works in dev but doesnt in prod